# Symmetric difference of a set with an empty set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, number-theory

The definition of symmetric difference of two sets $\alpha $ and $\beta$, $\alpha 
 \oplus \beta$ is defined as the set of all $x$ such that, $x \in (\alpha \cup \beta) - (\alpha \cap \beta)$.

If, $\alpha$ is some set with some members and $\beta = \phi$,

Will $\alpha \oplus \beta$ not contain "nothing"? I mean, If we take away all the elements of $\alpha \oplus \beta$, will we not get $\phi$ in end?

Comment: (This should have been posted on maths.SE instead of CS.SE.)

Comment: The symmetric difference of two sets includes every element that is in exactly one of either set. If one of the sets is the null set, then the symmetric difference is all the elements in the non-empty set, as all those elements are in exactly one of the sets. If it helps, you can think of it being analogous to the XOR operation in Boolean logic.

Comment: In fact, $\alpha \oplus \emptyset = \alpha$ is empty only if $\alpha$ itself is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $\alpha = \{1,2\}$ and $\beta=\emptyset$.

Then,

$$
\alpha\oplus\beta =
(\alpha\cup\beta)\setminus(\alpha\cap\beta) =
(\{1,2\}\cup\emptyset)\setminus(\{1,2\}\cap\emptyset) =
(\{1,2\})\setminus(\emptyset) = \{1,2\}
$$

So, no, $\alpha\oplus\beta$ is not "nothing", in general.